# How to access converter from code in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, converters

I have a converter in the code behind called `StringToIntConverter` I try using it in xaml binding like this where s is the project namespace:

```
Converter={s:StringToIntConverter}
```

But it says that it is missing an assembly reference. What am I doing wrong?

I know there is some way to put it as a resource and then reference the resource but I am not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<Some.Resources>
    <s:StringToIntConverter x:Key="StringToIntConverter"/>
</Some.Resources>
<!-- ... -->
Converter={StaticResource StringToIntConverter}
```

**Curly braces indicate a [markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee855815.aspx)**, they cannot just be used arbitrarily to instantiate objects, but for convenience you *could* turn your converter into a markup extension.

Something like:

```cs
public class StringToIntConverter : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
{
    //...

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

Then the code you used would work just fine!

---

Also note that you could use the binding in XML-element syntax to instantiate converters in place as well, e.g.

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="String">
            <Binding.Converter>
                <s:StringToIntConverter />
            </Binding.Converter>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 3):

Uhm - normally it goes something like this if I understand your question. You have created a converter right? In you XAML you need to add a reference to the assembly like this.

```
xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:Shared.Converters;assembly=Shared"
```

even if it is in the same assembly - something like...

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ItemMaster"
```

Now you need to create a staticResource for whatever converter you want to use.

```
<converters:CostMethodToBooleanConverter x:Key="CostMethodToBooleanConverter"/>
```

Then you can use it.

```
IsEnabled="{Binding SelectedItem, Converter={StaticResource ReverseCostMethodToBooleanConverter}, ElementName=OemOriginalCostMethod}"/>
```

Does that help?

Comment: I am not sure what you are saying by declaring the local namespace, do you really need both, what does the shared property mean?